# Cannot localise infoplist.strings

Tags: iphone, xcode

I tried to add a localised value to Info.plist using the recommended InfoPlist.strings

Do I need to keep the key also in Info.plist?

My Info.plist

```
 <key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
```

My localized strings

```
en.proj
  -> InfoPlist.strings
    /* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */ 
    CFBundleName = "ABC-EN";

it.proj
  -> InfoPlist.strings
    /* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */ 
    CFBundleName = "ABC-IT";
```

If I keep the key in Info.Plist as above, in the code, a variable which should have the key value

```
_localisedName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];
```

is returning the string which is in Info.plist (myApp)
If I remove `CFBundleName` from Info.plist the string is < nil >

There is another setting which I am missing?
I have tried adding and removing both file from the copy bundle (without any change).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was rather "complicated" to search for it, but I eventually find it out, I hope it will be useful for someone else

```
_localisedName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedInfoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/localizedInfoDictionary

> **localizedInfoDictionary**
>
> Returns a dictionary with the keys from the bundle’s localized property list.
>
> - (NSDictionary *)localizedInfoDictionary
>
> Return Value
> A dictionary with the keys from the bundle’s localized property list (InfoPlist.strings).
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method uses the preferred localization for the current user when determining which resources to return. If the preferred localization is not available, this method chooses the most appropriate localization found in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing a setting, you're calling the wrong method. You need to call one of the localized string methods, such as:

```
_localisedName = NSLocalizedString(@"CFBundleName", nil);
```

Comment: thanks, but it did not work. I tried `_localisedName = NSLocalizedString(@"CFBundleName", nil);` and `_localisedName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"CFBundleName", nil)];`, the former is returning `CFBundleName`, the latter < nil >. And I see the string well in the bundle `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-abcProducts/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`